# Can't get metaSendsEscape to work

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, vim, urxvt, alt

I previously used Manjaroi3, when I enabled xrvt*metaSendsEscape: true
it just worked.

I got tired of all the complicated stuff that came with running arch, nothing against arch, I just got sidetracked with problems and workarounds way too much.
So I switched to Ubuntu, I am running version 18.04LTS with i3wm.

When I set up rxvt-unicode, I can't get metaSendsEscape to work inside neovim.

**I have tried the following:**

- I have gone into ubuntu, disabled every alt-keyboardshortcut I could find.
- Downloaded gnome-tweaks and set alt to meta & alt
- Tried seemingly every combination of Xterm, xterm, URxvt, . * in .Xresources
- Tried altSendsEscape with every combination I could think of
- Tried remapping with xmodmaps\, my keypress on left alt now gives meta-L
- Googled for days, now when I search for metaSendsEscape, the whole page is populated   with purple links

I think something is stealing the alt/meta when I press it, before it reaches urxvt or nvim. I don't know, i'm desperate.

**The goal:**

> Use alt + h j k l to move between splits.
>
> Use alt + anything to exit insertmode and do that action, not moving between windows.

That's how I had it in Manjaroi3, I want it back. I miss it so.

I'll post all of my config files:

- .Xresources > https://pastebin.com/yEcWVA15
- .xintric only contains one line

> xrdb ~/.Xresources

- .Xdefaults only contains 3 lines.

> xterm*metaSendsEscape: true
>
> *metaSendsEscape: true
>
> URxvt.metaSendsEscape: true

- .bashrc > https://pastebin.com/kv4rbXKx
- init.vim > https://pastebin.com/v9c1qW3v
- .i3/config > https://pastebin.com/MnwuyiT0
- .tmux.conf (for good measure. even though the problem persists outside and inside tmux) > https://pastebin.com/MeD8s76x
- .xmodmap > https://pastebin.com/xHkDSXK4
- **xev** output.
- **showkey -s** output

**xev output:**

> KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
>       root 0x51f, subw 0x0, time 27037188, (551,529), root:(3517,576),
>       state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
>       root 0x51f, subw 0x0, time 27038381, (551,529), root:(3517,576),
>       state 0x8, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False

**showkey -s output:**

> **normal keypresses ____________________**
>
> 0x38
>
> 0xb8
>
> 0x38 0xb8
>
> 0x38
>
> 0xb8
>
> 0x38
>
> **Holding it down ____________________**
>
> 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38
>
> 0x38
>
> 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0x38 0xb8
>
> **Spamming it franticly ____________________**
>
> 0x38
>
> 0xb8
>
> 0x38 0xb8 0x38
>
> 0xb8 0x38
>
> 0xb8 0x38 0xb8 0x38
>
> 0xb8 0x38 0xb8 0x38
>
> 0xb8 0x38 0xb8 0x38
>
> 0xb8 0x38 0xb8 0x38 0xb8
>
> 0x38
>
> 0xb8
>
> 0x38 0xb8
>
> 0x38 0xb8

Any suggestions are accepted with incredible enthusiasm, I will try anything, but I am not going to install manjaro again, as it took too much of my time right now. Down the road, I'll probably go back. But for now, Ubuntu.

Comment: `nmap <silent> <M-k> :wincmd k<CR>` looks fine although `:nnoremap` is best practice.  `escape-time 0` in your tmux.conf also is fine. Try `:checkhealth nvim` anyways to verify that no problems are detected. 

More generally there is way too much going on here,  it should _not_ be complicated. Usually it's just "enable meta-as-escape" and you're done. Try a different terminal, such as gnome-terminal.

Xdefaults, xmodmap, blah blah blah should not be needed.

Comment: _Use alt + anything to exit insertmode and do that action_

 should work by default since ~Nvim 0.3.1 (maybe earlier). Always mention the version you are using ...

Comment: @JustinM.Keyes I reinstalled python3-neovim python-neovim and neovim itself, and i went trough the whole install-process on neovim's github page, and now it works! Thank you for leading me to the right path